# How would you divide this relative clause?

Tags: relative-clauses

I'm an English teacher. There is a point I couldn't decide. In order to teach the relative clauses to my students better, I plan to divide them into two clauses. How would you divide this sentence?

"I liked the pen you gave to Mike."

I'd divide like this but I can't be sure.

You gave the pen to Mike. I liked it.

Comment: Your "divided" suggestion looks more like it came from an "original" *You gave Mike **the pen I liked***, which conveys a difference nuance to your original. Why would you propose reversing the order of the "primary" subject *(**I**)* just because you want to split it into two separate sentences?

Comment: I agree with your division, except I'd use an indefinite article for the first occurrence of "pen": "You gave a pen to Mike; I liked the pen."

Comment: I'd say that the variables can be represented as "I liked pen x" + "you gave x to Mike".

Answer (score -3, accepted):

> **I liked  the  pen ( which /that)  you  gave to  Mke**

That is the sentence  you  gave

It can be divided  into two sentences as  shown below.

> **I  liked  a pen.You  gave  it (the pen )  to   Mike.**

As  Fumble  Fingers rightly  pointed   out in  his  comment, the sentence  reads  better  this  way.

> **You gave Mike the  pen    (that/ which) I liked**

Now this  sentence  can be  divided into  two  sentences  as below.

> **You  gave  a  pen  to  Mike. I liked  it  (the  pen)**

When  you  divide the  sentences,  you can not  say **the**  pen for the  first time.  .we  usually do not  repeat  **a noun**  for  the second time.

Comment: I would like to know  the  mistake  in my answer.

Comment: Those  are the  rules  I know  which  are found in grammar books.

Comment: @cascabel.could you  please prove  that  I am wrong?    I  did  not  that  it did  not  need citations

Comment: I agree with your second version.  This is very similar to what Sandy Thompson proposed in her dissertation: Thompson, Sandra A.  Fall, 1970.  Relative Clause Structures and Constraints on Types of Complex Sentences, Working Papers in Linguistics 6, Columbus: Information Science Research Center, Ohio State University, 20‑40.

Comment: @  Greg  Lee.  Is  my  first  verson  wrong and  the  second  right.? Thank  you anyway.

Comment: "I liked pen x" + "you gave x to Mike" would be better.